# Running zonal statistics on multiple raster tiles using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I'm new to QGIS (2.18.11). I've got OS Terrain 50 elevation data, in around 150 ASC tiles (10 km x 10 km) covering my whole area of interest (north-east Scotland). There is just a single band. I've got a grid of 1 km squares for my area of interest (made using TomBio plugin).

I'd like to extract mean elevation values per 1 km square (I may look for further stats later but mean is fine for starters). I've used Zonal Statistics to do this on one tile at a time and it adds a field to the Table of Attributes of the TomBio grid. That's all fine, and just what I need - except, is there a quicker way to do it for all 150 tiles at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

You could make a virtual raster (vrt) which will be quicker than merging them all (which is another option but will result in a huge file - so you will need to probably set the merge process to output a BigTiff).  A VRT is a much lighter-weight solution for your needs than a merge.  To build a VRT go `Raster->Miscellaneous->Build Raster Catalogue`  Then do your stats on the vrt.  For more information on the VRT see the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) (this will let you tweak the settings)

Answer (score 1):

Using R.

```
 require(raster)
 require(foreign)
 require(labgeo)
 require(dplyr)
 require(tidyverse)
 require(RQGIS)

#set QGIS directory
qgis_env <-set_env(root ='C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18') 
set_env()
open_app()

-Function and parametrs.

#entrada = folder with all rasters in .tif
#saida = folder witch zonal polygon will be dropped
#bacia = polygons

zonalTop = function(entrada, saida, bacia){

  nomesRasters = list.files(entrada, pattern="*.tif$")
  lerRasterCompl = list.files(entrada, pattern="*.tif$", full.names = TRUE)
  rasters = lapply(lerRasterCompl, raster)


  for (i in 1:length(rasters)){

    run_qgis(alg = "qgis:zonalstatistics",
             INPUT_RASTER = rasters[[i]],
             RASTER_BAND = 1,
             INPUT_VECTOR = bacia,
             GLOBAL_EXTENT = 1,
             OUTPUT_LAYER = paste(saida, tools::file_path_sans_ext(nomesRasters[[i]]),".shp", sep = ""))
  }

  nomesDbf = list.files(saida, pattern="*.dbf$")
  lerDbfCompl = list.files(saida, pattern="*.dbf$", full.names = TRUE)
  Dbfs = lapply(lerDbfCompl, read.dbf)

  for (i in 1:length(Dbfs)){

    names(Dbfs[[i]]) = paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(nomesDbf[i]), names(Dbfs[[i]]),  sep="_")

  }


  Dbfs = clean_names(do.call("cbind", Dbfs))

  return(Dbfs)

}


- Runnin Function Example

anch10k = zonalTop("E:/artigo_declividade/morfomometriatif/anchi/",
                   "E:/artigo_declividade/morfomometriatif/anchi/shapes10k",
                   bacia)
```